# Any way to include a pdf into a cfdocument process?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfdocument, cfpdf

Using CF document I am converting cfml into PDF. My process involves having an inner cfm included into an outer cfm. The outer puts a bunch of pretty stuff around the borders of each page, the inner is the meat of the data.

Now I'm at a point where instead of including a cfm I need to include a pdf, so my pretty border would be drawn around an existing pdf document, and output as a pdf document.

Using a cfinclude to a pdf inside a cfdocument tag results in a binary to string output so I have my pretty border surrounding a bunch of gibberish.

So how can I create a pdf out of my border cfm and an existing pdf?

Comment: cfdocument converts _HTML and CSS_ to PDF. You can use cfpdf to merge multiple PDF files, or to convert a PDF to an image (which can then be included in HTML, decorated, and converted with cfdocument again).

Comment: as far as I can tell merging with cfpdf will just join docs together, I need to window one doc within the one I'm currently creating. Writing the inner doc to an image and then including that could work, I just worry about possible quality degradation.

Comment: Yep, merging will not do what you need. It just stitches separate pages together into one file. What about applying one of them as a watermark over the other? That *might* work to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Don't worry about problems before they exist - there should be no reason a TIFF on high quality would degrade quality...

Comment: @leigh - Water Marking seems to work best though it's weird that it's point of origin for position is the lower left corner instead of the upper left. Any idea what's up with that?

Comment: @invertedSpear - That is actually the normal convention with pdfs. Reason is to ensure consistent positioning across devices (see pdf reference manual under device vs user space). Maybe CF was *supposed to* do some sort of translation in the background. But it does not. So the CF docs are wrong if they imply otherwise.

Comment: @Leigh - Just realized I owe you some answer rep for the watermark suggestion. If you want to convert your comment to an answer so I can accept it.